# Formar un array de objetos a partir de un formulario

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hola estoy tratando de formar un array que debo enviar ciertos datos dentro de un objeto al backend, el  servicio donde hago el seguimiento de los datos que se ingresan al formulario es

```
export class RegisterService {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  Info1: new FormControl('', null),
  Info2: new FormControl('', null),
  Data1: new FormControl('', null),
  Data2: new FormControl('', null),
  Data3: new FormControl('', null),
  Data4: new FormControl('', null),
  OpBase: new FormControl('', null)
  });
}
```

El código detrás del componente

```
constructor(public service: RegisterService){}

//Tengo que enviar los datos estructurados de esta forma: 
data: any = [{
    Info1: "",
    Info2: "",
    Objeto1: {
        Data1: "",
        Data2: "",
        Data3: "",
        Data4: "",
    },
    Objeto2: {
        OpBase: ""
    }
}];

//Metodo donde envío los datos
onRegister(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    console.log(this.service.form.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recrear la estructura completamente al crear el reactiveForms de la siguiente manera:

```js
export class RegisterService {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    Info1: new FormControl('', null),
    Info2: new FormControl('', null),
    Objeto1: new FormGroup({

      Data1: new FormControl('', null),
      Data2: new FormControl('', null),
      Data3: new FormControl('', null),
      Data4: new FormControl('', null),
    }),

    Objeto2: new FormGroup({
      OpBase: new FormControl('', null)
    })
  });
}
```

Para representar un sub grupo en el html solo necesitas hacer esto:

```html
<form [formControl]="tuReactiveForm">

  //...Tus controles sin embeber.

  <ng-container formGroupName="Objeto1">
    //... Mas controles como si no estuvieran embebidos.
  </ng-container>

  //Lo mismo para Objeto2


</form>
```

Despues, cuando hagas el envio de tu formulario (que espero que este global la variable `form`):

```js
submit() {

  //Tomamos los datos del formulario ya construido. 
  const modelo = this.form.value

  //Como debe ser un array pues creamos uno por fuerza
  const modeloArray = [modelo]

  //Ahora lo puedes enviar a tu servicio. 



}
```